# FBX button missing from export

Tags: export

I'm quite new to Blender but and I'm not sure why the FBX button is missing can somebody

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to "preferences".

Select "add-ons" tab.

Search for "fbx".

Activate the add-on.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot I didnt think you would reply that fast lol

Comment: if this answer is correct for you, please check the "accepted button". This is useful for future users on the same issue.